# How to integrate Xcode Server CI for project using Cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods, xcode-server

I'm setting up CI for a project using CocoaPods. I set up Xcode server locally on my Mac. Pod directory is not under source control, so put

```
pod install
```

in my 'Before Integration' script for my Bot, and got 'pod: command not found' error.

I certainly have pods installed on my machine, how do I make it visible for the server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can also use this line in the beginning of your trigger and you can run all other commands without using /usr/local/bin

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

But i would recommend to commit your Pods into the repository, so the CI does not have to care about it.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your CI service can't resolve the `pod` symlink.  I had a similar problem on a past Jenkins machine.  Run `which pod` to find the path to the pod binary, and call the binary directly from your CI service:

```
➜  ~ which pod
/usr/local/bin/pod
```

In your script:

```
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, solved the error, got another 'Trigger script exited with code: 1', will read server logs now.

Comment: @keith Have you solved 'Trigger script exited with code: 1'?